# App rejected with reason 2.9

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My app had 5 tab bars out of which 4 were working fine. The 5th one is for the phase II of app, so we added a label saying "coming soon" in 5h tab.
The app got rejected saying:

*

> Your app appears to be a pre-release, test, or trial version with a
>   limited feature set. Apps that are created for demonstration or trial
>   purposes are not appropriate for the App Store.

*

But what if we want to inform user that 5th tab will be a feature and will be available soon?
Thanks
Please help.

Comment: it seems that they consider your app as incomplete app. its better you add that tab in future version of app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on AppStore approval are off topic, but in this case the answer seems pretty clear. Remove the fifth tab until it does something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not about programming as defined by the [help]. Legal questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/, instead.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple's policy you cannot advertise about anything from within the app.Apple doesn't allow you to do marketing of things that do not exist. The only solution is not to display anything like that in the app. Your users can only know about the features when the features are implemented and ready for them to use.